# JAVA : change font's size in java

Tags: java, fonts

I'm trying to make image file with custom font.

I get my font files by use `Font[] fonts = graphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts();`
like this.

and I create Graphics2D and set font with that fonts.

But, my problem is I can't set my font's size!!!

I know that when I create my font file with `Font.createFont()`, I can set size by myself.

But I wonder how to set font's size after we create font file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28float%29

Using  Component.getFont().deriveFont(9.0f)